# How to workaround problem in git add with absolute paths and symlinks

Tags: git, macos, ubuntu, vmware

The Git issue is described in details [here](http://bit.ly/h6QObX).

I'm on OS X 10.6.5, working on the project that runs only on Ubuntu.

I run Ubuntu 10.10 x86 as a guest in VMWare Fusion 3.1.2.

My work is in `~/projects/` on OS X. I mount the `projects` directory in the Ubuntu guest via VMWare's hgfs: `/mnt/hgfs/projects`.

In Ubuntu I symlink `/mnt/hgfs/projects` to `~/projects`.

As a part of my workflow I have to run a script that does

`(cd /absolute/path/to/project/ && git add /absolute/path/to/project/some/file)`

Due to the above issue the script does not work. I need to workaround this somehow.

What should be left as is:

- My files must be on OS X, in `~/projects`. I have other non-Ubuntu stuff there, and I'd hate to keep track of several directories on several OSes. Also, I should be able to edit my files in my favorite OS X-only editor.
- Files must be instantly synchronized between Ubuntu and OS X. I should not wait and I should not run anything by hand.
- I do not want to change the script.
- I'd like files in Ubuntu to stay in `~/projects`.

I guess that, given these requirements, my options are not that numerous.

The one I see is to mount the OS X `~/projects` to Ubuntu `~/projects` directly.

The question is, what is the most robust way to do it? Last time I looked, SSHFS and NFS support in OS X was flaky (but perhaps I did not look that well).

Is there a way to change hgfs mount point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy:

```
rm ${HOME}/projects # Remove symlink
mkdir ${HOME}/projects
sudo mount -t vmhgfs .host:/projects "${HOME}/projects"
```